# Laravel image validation just reloads page and does nothing

Tags: php, laravel, post, input

so the problem is I have image upload in my form, I did this before on other project and everything worked fine, but now for some reason I can't use `dd()` command to see what is sent from `<form>`. Here is my controller code:

```
    

        $data = $request->validate([
        'model_id' => 'required',
        'part_name' => 'required',
        'part_category' => 'required',
        'make_years' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'identifier_number' => '',
        'part_image' => 'image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ]);

    dd($data);
```

And this is my blade part where image's input is:

```
    <div class="form-row row-cols-1" style="margin-right: 0px;margin-left: 0px;">
                                            <label for="part_image" class="custom-file-upload btn btn-primary text-nowrap d-flex d-sm-flex d-md-flex d-lg-flex justify-content-center align-items-center justify-content-sm-center align-items-sm-center justify-content-md-center align-items-md-center justify-content-lg-center align-items-lg-center justify-content-xl-center align-items-xl-center">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>Įkelti nuotrauką
    </label>
    <input id="part_image" name="part_image" type="file" hidden>
    @error('part_image')
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
    @enderror
    
    </div>
```

So basically if I comment `part_image` validation in my controller, `dd()` function works, and I see all sent variables through `POST`, but if I try uncomment image validation, when I submit, page just reloads and I can't even see any errors or dump message. What could be the problem? It's probably some silly mistake, but I can find it.
I also have stated on my form `enctype="multipart/form-data"` so that's not the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not reaching dd() because you surely have validation errors, but you are not properly displaying them in your blade view. If you didn't have any validation errors control flow would reach dd() and would print results inside controller. $request->validate(...) automatically redirects you back, so what you can do is to correctly display the errors in your blade view, preferable all at once to debug:

```
@if ($errors->any())
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
      @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
  </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you for response, It's actually very nice advice, I should just leave this on view, just to see all the errors, however then I added this code, for no reason it started validating image successfully, I tried deleting this code it and still validation passes fine. I don't actually know what changed, but it seems like problem solved on it's own

Comment: You're welcome, glad it's working now.